# Getting duplicate component id exception on WAS 8.5.* and same is working on WAS 6.1

Tags: jsp, jsf, websphere

As part of the Application upgrade, we have moved from the WebSphere Application Server(WAS) version 6.1 to 8.5.0.

I think the JSF version supported on WAS 8.5.0 is JSF1.2 which is different from WAS6.1 which might suppport JSF1.1.

We are getting a JSP exception as below during when the page reloads. **And this exception is being seen only WAS8.5.0 but the same scenario is working fine on WAS6.1.**

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate component id of: paperless_prop_lrb, for component location: {Component-Path : [Class: com.company.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /inbox/mobile/inbox.jsp][Class: com.company.faces.component.html.HtmlScriptCollector,Id: j_id_jsp_844175260_4][Class: com.company.faces.taglib.core.LoadResourceBundleTag$LoadBundleComponent,Id: paperless_prop_lrb]}

Kindly help if you faced a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

has any previous installation of the application on was 8.5 failed? if yes, try to uninstall the application, search the WAS directory for any reference of the application and delete it. Then re-install the application.

Comment: There are no deployment failures on was 8.5. And for the first time on load my journey is working, but if we revisit the page its throwing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by making my view as a transient, with the below line

context.getViewId().setTransient(true);